# operator<< stackoverflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Consider the following code :

```
class TextMessage{
public :
    TextMessage(){};
    TextMessage(std::string _text):text(_text){}
    std::string text;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, const TextMessage & m);
};
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, const TextMessage & m){
    return os << "text message : " << m.text;
}
```

Why on earth :

- does Visual 2010 issue a [C4717 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97c54274%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in operator `<<`
- does `std::cout << textMsgInstance;` crashes by stackoverflow as predicted by Visual ?

Btw, replacing `m.text` by `m.text.c_str()` works.

Comment: This works fine for me, so there must be something else wrong elsewhere in your code...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing that you failed to `#include <string>`. Thus, when the compiler comes to output a `std::string`, it can't, and starts looking for implicit conversions- and your implicit constructor to a TextMessage looks like just the bill. But wait- now we're outputting a TextMessage in the TextMessage's output function, and bam.

Comment: I think so too, but doesn't `std::string` need to be a complete type before using it as a (non-pointer) member variable?  It's the stream insertion operators that are missing, apparently.

Comment: @Ben:  Some headers other than `<string>` in the Visual C++ Standard Library implementation bring in `std::string` but only `<string>` brings in the stream operator overloads.  For example, if you `#include <iostream>` (and don't include `<string>`), then `int main() { std::string s; }` will work, but `int main() { std::string s; std::cout << s; }` will not.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Perfectly Standard-compliant to define the `std::string` class but not it's insertion/extraction operators in some non-`<string>` header.

Comment: If this is correct, then it's a good reason to declare the constructor `explicit`...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that a temporary TextMessage was created on the stack with the string constructor. And including <string> worked. But how could the code compile if I didn't include <string> in the first place ?

Comment: @Calvin1602: It's perfectly legal for any Standard header to include all or parts (in this case, the definition of `std::string`) of other Standard headers. So it's perfectly legal for you to `#include <iostream>` and get the full definition of `std::string`, but only get the insertion/extraction operators if you `#include <string>`.

Comment: @DeadMG Could you indicate where in the standard it says "all or parts"?
All I find in my copy is (§17.4.4.1) "A C++ header may include other C++
headers."  No mention of parts.  (Obviously, this is an academic
question: whether including just a part is legal or not, it's what most
implementations do, and we have to live with it.)

Answer (score 6):

Only thing I can think of is that it doesn't have an operator<< for std::string so it looks for a conversion and finds the one argument constructor TextMessage(std::string).

It is often advisable to prevent unexpected calls to one argument constructors by making them explicit.

```
explicit TextMessage(std::string _text):text(_text){}
```

Then it will not consider the constructor for implicit conversions.

Comment: +1 for making the constructor explicit. Inhibiting implicit conversions is always a good idea.

Comment: +1. A few weeks ago I swore to always write `explicit` on my constructors, and bam, already forgot.

Answer (score 3):

Its because `m.text` is `std::string` and it gets converted inside the operator to `TextMessage` and the operator is called again.